# draw k times from n numbers with replacement, each number appears at least m times

Tags: combinatorics

The objective is to draw $k$ times from $n$ numbers with replacement and with remembering the order. What is the probability $P(k,n,m)$ that every number ($1\ldots n$) is drawn at least $m$ times?

For $m=0$ the probability is $P(k,n,0)=1$.

For $m=1$ ([1498003](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498003/632893)) the probability is $P(k,n,1)=\mathcal{S}_k^{(n)}n!/n^k$ in terms of the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Is there an efficient way of calculating $P(k,n,m)$ for higher values of $m$?

Here's an inefficient way to calculate these probabilities in *Mathematica* by enumerating all possible drawing results:

```
f[k_Integer /; k >= 0, n_Integer /; n >= 1] := f[k, n] = 
   Reverse@Accumulate@Reverse@BinCounts[
        Min[BinCounts[#, {1, n + 1, 1}]] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], k],
        {0, Floor[k/n] + 1, 1}]/n^k;
P[k_Integer /; k >= 0, n_Integer /; n >= 1, m_Integer /; m >= 0] := 
  With[{L = f[k, n]}, If[m >= Length[L], 0, L[[m + 1]]]]
```

Test of the known formula for $m=1$:

```
With[{k = 8, n = 3},
  P[k, n, 1] == StirlingS2[k, n]*n!/n^k]
(* True *)
```

---

## update: faster code based on solution

[@GCab's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3223771/632893) gives an efficient recipe for calculating these probabilities. Simplifying the multinomials and rising factorials a bit,

$$
P(k,n,m)
=\frac{1}{n^k} \frac{k!}{(k-nm)!} \sum_{l_j\ge0\\l_1+l_2+\ldots+l_n=k-n m}\binom{k-nm}{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n}\frac{1}{(1+l_1)^{\bar{m}}(1+l_2)^{\bar{m}}\ldots(1+l_n)^{\bar{m}}}\\
=\frac{1}{n^k} \sum_{l_j\ge0\\l_1+l_2+\ldots+l_n=k-n m}\binom{k}{l_1+m,l_2+m,\ldots,l_n+m}\\
=\frac{1}{n^k} \sum_{a_j\ge m\\a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=k}\binom{k}{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n}
$$

In *Mathematica*,

```
P[k_, n_, m_] := 
  1/n^k * Total[(Multinomial @@ #)*(Multinomial @@ Tally[#][[All,2]]) & /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[m, k-(n-1)*m]]]
```

The extra factor of `Multinomial @@ Tally[#][[All,2]]` in this formula counts how many permutation of a given integer partition exist, because `IntegerPartitions` does not enumerate partitions that differ only by permutation.

### recursion

Still much faster is [@GCab's recursive solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3223771/632893): in *Mathematica*,

```
$RecursionLimit = 10^4;
R[k_, n_, m_] /; k < n*m = 0;
R[k_, n_, 0] = n^k;
R[k_, 1, m_] = 1;
R[k_, n_, m_] := R[k, n, m] = 
  n*(R[k-1, n, m] + Binomial[k-1, m-1]*R[k-m, n-1, m])
P[k_, n_, m_] := R[k, n, m]/n^k
```

With this recursion we can go to large values of $k$ easily:

```
P[1000, 100, 7] // N // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.245745, 2.4066*10^-8} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of combinatorial classes we get

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=n}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge m}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the EGF

$$\left(\exp(z)-\sum_{q=0}^{m-1} \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^n.$$

The desired quantity is then given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n^k} k! [z^k]
\left(\exp(z)-\sum_{q=0}^{m-1} \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^n.}$$

**Addendum.** For  computational purposes  it  is best  to use  a
recurrence like the one shown below.

```
X :=
(k, n, m) ->
1/n^k*k!*coeftayl((exp(z)-add(z^q/q!, q=0..m-1))^n,
                  z=0, k);

R :=
proc(k, n, m)
option remember;

    if n=1 then
        return `if`(k >= m, 1/k!, 0);
    fi;

    add(1/q!*R(k-q, n-1, m), q=m..k);
end;

XR := (k, n, m) -> 1/n^k*k!*R(k, n, m);
```

**Addendum, II.**  If we are required to use  integers only we can
use the  recurrence below  (e.g. for  implementation in  a programming
language that does not provide fractions as a data type).

```
R2 :=
proc(k, n, m)
option remember;

    if n=1 then
        return `if`(k >= m, 1, 0);
    fi;

    add(binomial(k,q)*R2(k-q, n-1, m), q=m..k);
end;

XR2 := (k, n, m) -> 1/n^k*R2(k, n, m);
```

Comment: That's very impressive, Marko! Thanks for your effort. This formula really allows some large scaling for the first time.

Comment: Very interesting indeed

Answer (score 1):

This the same as 
laying $k$ (distinguished, since you consider the extraction order) balls into $n$ (distinguished) bins
but allow me to change $k$ into $s$ so to keep $k$ for use as index, thus
 *laying $s$ (distinguished) balls into $n$ (distinguished) bins, each bin having at least $m$ balls*,
or equivalently
*writing words of length $s$, from the alphabet $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, with each character appearing at least $m$ times*.

Without the bound on $m$ (i.e. for $m=0$), there are $n^s$ ways of doing that, each represented by one term in the expansion of 
$$
\left( {x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,n} } \right)^{\,s} 
$$
Since
$$
\left( {x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,n} } \right)^{\,s}  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,j_{\,k} }  \\   {j_{\,1}  + \,j_{\,2} +\, \cdots +\,j_{\,n} \, = \,s}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   j_{\,1} ,\,j_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,j_{\,n}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\;x_{\,1} ^{j_{\,1} } \;x_{\,2} ^{j_{\,2} } \; \cdots \;x_{\,n} ^{j_{\,n} } } 
$$
then the multinomial coefficient counts the number of "occupancy" histograms with *distinguished* balls
corresponding to the same histogram when the balls are *undistinguished*.
(the number of histograms with *undist.* balls would be the number of weak [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $s$ into $n$ parts).

Now we are looking for
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 P(s,n,m) = \frac{{N(s,n,m)}}{{n^{\,s} }} = \frac{1}{{n^{\,s} }}\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {m\, \le \,j_{\,k} }  \\    {j_{\,1}  + \,j_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + j_{\,n} \, = \,s}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   j_{\,1} ,\,j_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,j_{\,n}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{n^{\,s} }}\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,k} }  \\    {l_{\,1}  + \,l_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + l_{\,n} \, = \,s - nm}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   m + l_{\,1} ,\,m + l_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,m + l_{\,n}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{n^{\,s} }}\frac{{s!}}{{\left( {s - nm} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,k} }  \\    {l_{\,1}  + \,l_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + l_{\,n} \, = \,s - nm}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\frac{{l_{\,1} !\,l_{\,2} ! \cdots l_{\,n} !}}{{\left( {m + l_{\,1} } \right)!\,\left( {m + l_{\,2} } \right)!\, \cdots \,\left( {m + l_{\,n} } \right)!}}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s - nm \\   l_{\,1} ,\,l_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,l_{\,n}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{n^{\,s} }}\frac{{s!}}{{\left( {s - nm} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,k} }  \\    {l_{\,1}  + \,l_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + l_{\,n} \, = \,s - nm}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s - nm \\   l_{\,1} ,\,l_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,l_{\,n}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\frac{1}{{\left( {1 + l_{\,1} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } \,\left( {1 + l_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } \, 
\cdots \,\left( {1 + l_{\,n} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } }}}  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where $x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }$ represents  the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Although other manipulations of the above formula are possible, I do not see it possible to reach to a closed
formula, unless (maybe) through the q-Stirling ? (*)

We can however establish a recursive relation in $s$ that might be more practical in computing.

Let's take the "words" scheme and indicate by $N^ *  (s,n,m)$ the 
*Number of words of length $s$, from the alphabet $\{1,cdots,n\}$, with one character repeated exactly$m-1$ times and the other at least $m$ times*.
That is
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 N^ *  (s,n,m) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {m\, \le \,j_{\,k} }  \\    {j_{\,1}  + \,j_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + \,j_{\,n - 1}  + m - 1\, = \,s}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   j_{\,1} ,\,j_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,j_{\,n - 1} ,\,m - 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {m\, \le \,j_{\,k} }  \\    {j_{\,1}  + \,j_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + \,j_{\,n - 1} \, = \,s - m + 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   j_{\,1} ,\,j_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,j_{\,n - 1} ,\,m - 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \frac{{s!}}{{\left( {s - m + 1} \right)!\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {m\, \le \,j_{\,k} }  \\    {j_{\,1}  + \,j_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + \,j_{\,n - 1} \, = \,s - m + 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s - m + 1 \\   j_{\,1} ,\,j_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,\,j_{\,n - 1}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\   m - 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right)N(s - m + 1,n - 1,m) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Then a word of length $s+1$, and parameters $n,m$ can be composed
 - either by adding any character to a word $(s,n,m)$,
 - or by adding the missing character to a word counted by $N^* (s,n,m)$.
Therefore we have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 N(s + 1,n,m) = n\left( {N(s,n,m) + N^ *  (s,n,m)} \right) =  \\ 
  = n\left( {N(s,n,m) + \left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\  m - 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right)N(s - m + 1,n - 1,m)} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
with a suitable tuning of the initial conditions / range of the parameters.

Note(*)
I stumbled now on learning that N(s,n,m) is related to the **m-associated Stirling** numbers of 2nd kind
$$
{{N(s,n,m)} \over {n!}} = S_{\,m} \left( {s,n} \right)
$$
re. for instance to these links [3](http://oeis.org/A000478), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63376), [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much! This formula is so much faster than the one I used so far, it will certainly help in discovering more closed expressions. Cheers!

Comment: As you suspected, the multinomial in the sum can be combined with the rising factorials into a single multinomial of $l_1+m,l_2+m,\ldots,l_n+m$. This gets rid of the prefactor of $s!/(s-n m)!$ as well. See the *Mathematica* code update.

Comment: @Roman: I modified a bit the introduction and added a recursion.

Comment: Very cool. This recursion is by far the fastest method so far, almost as good as having a closed formula. I am doing some more testing. Cheers!

Comment: @Roman:  glad for the appreciation: I do think that, computationally, the recursion would be the fastest method, specially since it involves just integers.