# Coupon Collection

Tags: probability

Define the Coupon Collection Problem with $n$ distinct coupons. What is the probability that after purchasing $k$ boxes, the collection is complete? My attempt at a solution was as follows: Let $X_{k}$ be the random variable that is $1$ if the collection is complete after $k$ purchases and $0$ otherwise.
$P(X_{k}=1) = \frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}{\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}}$

I used the stars and bars logic that there are $\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$total assignments. $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$ of them are satisfying. Am I right?.

Answer (score 1):

The events in your counting argument is are not equally probable so do not give the correct probability.

For example if $n=2$ and $k=2$ then your calculation would give $P(X_{2}=1) = \dfrac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{3}{1}} =\dfrac{1}{3}$ when the correct answer is clearly $\dfrac12$: the first box gives you a coupon with probability $1$ and there is a probability $\dfrac12$ that the second box gives you the other coupon.  Other small examples will reveal the same issue

As I say in response to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1498146/6460), the probability is $\dfrac{S_2(k,n) \, n!}{n^k}$ where $S_2(k,n)$ represents a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), sometimes written $\displaystyle\Bigl\lbrace{k\atop n}\Bigr\rbrace$.